# How to crop an image without using crop intent

Tags: android, android-intent

can anyone give me an example of how to write my own crop code. I mean, I dont want to go an cropping program, I want to do it in my application

Comment: https://github.com/choiboi/android-cropping-example

Comment: https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage

Comment: https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery/+/froyo/src/com/android/camera/CropImage.java